# Why Cursor is needed?

Tags: sql, cursor

When we can use loop with in the stored procedure then why do we need cursor. i.e. when we can perform the same opearation with stored procedure then why do we need cursor. I am a newbie so my question my sound a bit odd to some

Comment: You need to be more concrete than this - we cannot possibly answer such an open-ended question. What is the scenario? What are you trying to do? Also: **what** database? SQL = structured query language - that's not yet a database system, and these things are very often vendor-specific - different for SQL Server vs. Oracle vs. PostgreSQL vs. DB2 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cursor is just a loop, but over a set of values from a SQL query. If you're looping through sequential values, then I suppose you don't need to use a cursor and can just use a manual loop instead.